# Querying on related models using Laravel 4 and Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4 I have the following models and relations: Event which hasMany Record which hasMany Item. What I would like to do is something like this

```
Item::where('events.event_type_id', 2)->paginate(50);
```

This of cause doesn't work as Eloquent doesn't JOIN the models together when retrieving the records. So how do I go about this without just writing the SQL myself (which I would like to avoid as I want to use pagination).

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There is a request at Github though that would allow you to something like that: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1166

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading).

It works like this if you want to specify additional constraints:

```
Item::with(array('events' => function($query) {
    return $query->where('event_type_id', 2);
}))->paginate(50);
```

Comment: This works beautifully, but my site will have thousend of records and as far as I can see, eager loading works by using IN(...). Isn't this horribly inefficient compared to using SQL joins?

Comment: Since you're paginating, there's a limit. I wouldn't call it horrible, but I think this was considerably simpler to implement and gives us more flexibility for the kinds of queries we can run when fetching items.

Comment: If you'd do it with joins, you would have to somehow differentiate between the item's and the events' fields when hydrating the models, so there'd be some overhead, too. Plus, you're fetching less redundant data, since every item is only fetched once, even if it has multiple events.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pull request pending here https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/1951.

This will allow you to use a constraint on the has() method, something like this:

```
$results = Foo::has(array('bars' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%baz%');
}))
->with('bars')
->get();
```

The idea being you only return Foos that have related Bars that contain the string 'baz' in its title column.

It's also discussed here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1166. Hopefully it will be merged in soon. Works fine for me when I update my local copy of the Builder class with the updated code in the pull request.