# How to find category name from category value which is in different table in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

There are two table category and content.
Content table has id,category_id

Category table has category name and id

I have to fetch all the content from content table with category name which is in Category Table.

I don't want to use JOIN.

Please suggest me other query to use.

Controller

```
     $AllContent=Content::all();

    return View::make('ALL/Contents')->with('AllContent',$AllContent);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying on related models using Laravel 4 and Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821601/querying-on-related-models-using-laravel-4-and-eloquent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you don't want to use an SQL JOIN, as it is almost certainly the most efficient thing to do when you have one table relating to another by its primary key. But hey, who am I to judge?

A way you can do this is by using a subquery. In plain old SQL:

```
SELECT
    `content`.`id`,
    (
        SELECT `name`
        FROM `category`
        WHERE `id` = `content`.`category_id`
    ) AS `name`
FROM `content`
```

So, to do this using Laravel's query builder:

```
DB::table('content')
    ->select(['id'])
    ->selectSub(function ($query) {
        return $query->from('category')
                     ->where('id', '=', DB::raw('content.category_id'))
                     ->select('name')
    }, 'name')
    ->get();
```

I think that'll do what you want, anyway. But really, just use a JOIN.

---

If you **do** want to use a JOIN then you're somewhat better off. Again I'll give you the raw SQL first:

```
SELECT
    `content`.`id`,
    `category`.`name`
FROM `content`
LEFT JOIN `category`
    ON `content`.`category_id` = `category`.`id`
```

And now in Laravel's query builder:

```
DB::table('content')
    ->join('category', 'content.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
    ->select(['content.id', 'category.name'])
    ->get();
```

And now using Eloquent models:

```
// app/Models/Content.php
namespace App\Models;

class Content
{
    protected $table = 'content';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'category_id');
    }
}


// app/Models/category.php
namespace App\Models;

class Category
{
    protected $table = 'category';

    public function content()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Content', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Now you can use this model to do all sorts. For example, to do what you were originally trying:

```
// some controller somewhere
use App\Models\Content;

class SomeController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $content = Content::with('category')->get();

        return View::make('ALL/Contents')->with('AllContent', $content); 
    }
}

// views/ALL/Contents.blade.php
<ul>
    @foreach ($AllContent as $content)
        <li>
            {{ $content->id }} - {{ $content->category->name }}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

But alternatively you can return the content id/category name as a key=>value array:

```
// in the controller
$content = Content::with('category')->lists('category.name', 'id');

// in the view
<ul>
    @foreach ($AllContent as $id => $category)
        <li>
            {{ $id }} - {{ $category }}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This is all untested, but should work. If it doesn't, it should at least give you an idea of how it all goes together.

Comment: I don't know how to use join in this case

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi I've just edited the post to expand on how you'd do it with an SQL JOIN and then expanded on that into how that could then translate into Eloquent models. Hope it helps.